# Mutual Fund Data types in MS Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, stock

I am able to pull the stocks data in Excel sheet. Can i pull the Mutual Fund data in excel?

**say for ex**: Navi Nifty 50 Index Fund Direct Growth

Comment: You just need to know the symbol to use. What have you tried and where did you run into problems?

Comment: I can add stock in the excel and it works say for example: HDFC BANK LIMITED (XNSE:HDFCBANK), I can select this stock in the excel (using Stock Data type). But when i type any MF (ex: Navi nifty 50 index fund direct growth), it's not resolving. I am not sure i can add the MF in excel stock?

Comment: Try `Navi Nifty 50 Index-Dir-Gth` which works here.

Comment: Thank you Ron. It works for me too. How to find this ticker name? I need to find it for some other MF's also.

Comment: I typed `Navi Nifty 50` into a cell. Then selected that cell and "Stock Data". A few items popped up in the Data Selector window and I picked the most likely one.

Comment: got it. But it's not easy or straight forward to find it. I wanted to do for few MF's . I found for one other MF with different combination of words and search. It's worked. Let me figure out for the rest of the MFS. Thanks Ron

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a data connection, if they have an API end point

Using Data Connection:

1. Open Excel and navigate to the "Data" tab.
2. Click on "Get Data" or "From Web" (depending on your Excel version)
3. In the dialog box, enter the URL of the website or API endpoint that
   provides mutual fund data.
4. Follow the prompts to specify the data you want to import, such as
   fund names, NAV (Net Asset Value), or historical performance.
5. Configure any additional options, such as data refresh intervals.
6. Choose the location where you want to import the data (new
   worksheet, existing worksheet, or data model).
7. Click "Load" or "OK" to import the data into Excel. It will
   establish a connection to the data source and fetch the mutual fund
   data.

but you can also try to use googlesheets with the command googlefiance for example

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")
```